# Display data in modal

Tags: reactjs

I would like to pass several data in a modal. My modal works fine but does not display the data I want. I would like to display the data BY ID, but I get all the data. This is my code :

App.js :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Modal from "./Modal";
import PlayCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PlayCircle';

const App = (props) => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState([])


    return (
                <div>
                    {image.map((image) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={image.id}>
                                <img src={...}
                                    alt={image.title}
                                />
                                
                                <ExpandMoreIcon onClick={handleClick} />

                                
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Modal.js :

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = ({ showModal, image }) => {

    console.log("result", image);

    return (

            <div className="modal" > 
                    <div className='modal__content'>
                        <h1 className='modal__title'>{image.title}</h1>
                        <p className='modal__description'>{image.description}</h1>
                    </div>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Modal;
```

I think the problem comes from here `image={image}` in App.js because I get 8 tables in console.log("result", movie);

Answer (score 1):

```
{showModal && <Modal showModal={handleClick} image={image} />}
```

Your problem is your modal state is true/false value, so that's why once you trigger `showModal`, it will show all modals according to your number of images

The fix can be

*Note that I modified your state name to align with new state values*

```
const [modalImage, setModalImage] = useState(); //undefined as no image selected
const handleClick = (imageId) => {
   setModalImage(imageId);
};
```

Your elements will be like below

```
<ExpandMoreIcon onClick={() => handleClick(image.id)} />
{modalImage === image.id && <Modal showModal={() => handleClick(image.id)} image={image} />}
```

If you want to close the modal, you can reset `modalImage` state

```
onClick={() => handleClick(undefined)}
```

I just noticed that you also can move your modal out of the image loop, and potentially you can pass the entire `image` object to the modal too

The full implementation

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Modal from "./Modal";
import PlayCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PlayCircle';

const App = (props) => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState([])
    const [modalImage, setModalImage] = useState(); //no image selected

    const handleClick = (image) => {
        setModalImage(image);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
    }, []);


    return (
                <div>
                    {image.map((image) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={image.id}>
                                <img src={...}
                                    alt={image.title}
                                />
                                
                                <ExpandMoreIcon onClick={() => handleClick(image)} />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                    {modalImage && <Modal showModal={() => handleClick(modalImage)} image={modalImage} />}
                </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly. However, I did not understand how to close the modal, I created this in my modal  `<div className="close" onClick={...}><span>X</span>...</div>` but it doesn't seem to work with `onClick={() => handleClick(undefined)}`

Comment: You need to pass `onClose` attribute like this`{modalImage && <Modal showModal={() => handleClick(modalImage)} onClose={() => handleClick(undefined)} image={modalImage} />}`, and then you can call it inside your modal `<div className="close" onClick={props.onClose}><span>X</span></div>` @Daemes

Answer (score 0):

Both the map item and the image state array are named `image` in your code here;

```js
image.map((image) => {
   /// your code
})
```

which could be the ambiguity that led to showing the whole array of data instead of one image in the array.